# complex numbers equation with 3rd power

Tags: complex-numbers

I have problem with this equation. Can someone help mi with it?

\begin{align*} z^3+3z^2+3z &= i - 1 \end{align*}

That's what I have:

\begin{align*} (z+1)^3 = i \end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

If ${(z+1)^{3}=i}$, what we essentially want to do is find the cube roots of ${i}$. This is much easier than it sounds. Firstly, we represent ${i}$ in polar form. This is simply

$${e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\right)}}$$

This can be seen with an argand diagram (it's just an application of Euler's formula):

$${=cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)=i}$$

Now raising this to the one third power gives

$${\Rightarrow z+1=e^{\frac{i}{3}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)}}$$

Simply plugging in ${n=\{0,1,2\}}$ will give the three roots we need,

${z+1=e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}}, e^{\frac{5i\pi}{6}},e^{\frac{3\pi i}{2}}}$

(plugging these again into Euler's formula and subtracting $1$ will give you your answers for $z$).

Comment: Can I do it without e? Cuz I haven't this on my math. But rly thx for this answer! If it's only way, I will do that!

Comment: @Joe No problem! Certainly you could probably set up a system of equations, but it'll get messy very quickly. The square root of $i$ done without Euler's formula, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z49hXoN4KWg . I would highly, highly recommend you learn Euler's formula. If you have an understanding of Calculus, you can find the derivation using Taylor Series here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcrQ3rPUYjc and if you don't know Taylor Series, you can find an amazing explanation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d6DsjIBzJ4&t=973s

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. And, since $i=e^{\pi i/2}$, $z+1$ is one of these three numbers:

- $e^{\pi i/6}\left(=\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right)$,
- $e^{5\pi i/6}\left(=-\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right)$,
- $e^{9\pi i/6}(=e^{3\pi i/2}=-i)$.